# How to enter spacebar space character in Block Composer - ShowText()?

Tags: pdfclown

When I'm using ShowText's whitespace (spacebar spaces) (in Block Composer), it only works in middle of the texts but not at the beginning of the text.  I assumed it is because PDFClown do trim the whitespace characters.

So is there special character I can use in place of whitespace so it won't get trimmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, leading whitespace is purposely trimmed off: if you need to indent your paragraph then use the [BlockComposer.ShowBreak(SizeF)](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/composition/BlockComposer.html) method specifying a horizontal offset (for example blockComposer.ShowBreak(new SizeF(10,0))).

Comment: While this in general may be handy, consider the case of a font in which the space glyph is not empty but instead e.g. a rectangle (for a font having all its glyphs inside a rectangle). In such a case an indentation is not the same as leading space characters.

Comment: That's a good point, although somewhat academic, ain't it? ;) In such a peculiar case, I would suggest to remap the character encoding for that entry (AFAIK, even the current PDF spec seems to reserve the code-point 32 to space char for word spacing purposes [PDF:1.7:9.3.3])